# select tag with multiple collections in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I have this select tag pulling a collection of pages for the user to choose from:

```
<%= f.select(:read_more, Page.all.collect{|page| [page.title, page.section.name.to_s+"/"+page.slug.to_s]}, {:include_blank => false}) %>
```

But I also want to add a second collection, bio's to the same select box. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sum it

```
Page.all.collect{|page| [page.title, page.section.name.to_s+"/"+page.slug.to_s]} + Bio.all.collect{|bio| [bio.name, bio.age] }
```

So,

```
<%= f.select(:read_more, Page.all.collect{|page| [page.title, page.section.name.to_s+"/"+page.slug.to_s]} + Bio.all.collect{|bio| [bio.name, bio.age] }, {:include_blank => false}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something similar to what you're trying to accomplish [How can I elegantly construct a form for a model that has a polymorphic association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653109/how-can-i-elegantly-construct-a-form-for-a-model-that-has-a-polymorphic-associati)
The problem is not how to display items in select box, but rather how to retrieve the value later in controller.